# Is it possible to invalidate spring mvc sessions if browser is closed or power got off?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC I am able to get all the session by the following code.

```
int active= sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().size();
List<String> activeSessionsId = new ArrayList<String>();
for(int i=0;i<active;i++){
    List<SessionInformation> si=
         sessionRegistry.getAllSessions(sessionRegistry.getAllPrincipals().get(i), false);
    for(SessionInformation s:si){
        System.out.println("SessionId="+s.getSessionId());
        activeSessionsId.add(s.getSessionId());
    }
}
```

Here sessionRegistory is my spring given bean I configured it like this:

```xml
<beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />
```

And autowired in my controller like this:

```
@Resource(name="sessionRegistry")
private SessionRegistryImpl sessionRegistry;
```

I thought activeSessionsId list would be contain only active session but it contain all the users session that I logged in and passed by spring security. For some users I closed the browser without logout and I was expecting this session won't be add in my activeSessionsId
list but it is not like that .

I observed all sessionId got added in activeSessionsId.

Actually Concept wise I know the session creation is happening by server side .But Please any one let me know whatever I am trying is it possible or not in a case of spring MVC.

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of server, you must admit that you cannot know if browser if closed. Ok, you can try to use javascript to send something when closing window, but *anything* can happen :

- the network can go down at any point (system, modem, proxies), voluntarily or not
- power can go off, voluntarily or not
- javascript can be disabled
- user can use a *headless browser* (Selenium, Python or Java or ... code) that could choose to ignore all or part of javascript

So use javascript if you want and it will work in the great majority of use cases, but always keep a session timeout for the unwanted silent disconnection that can still occur whatever you do.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when I close the browser, the server i'm talking to will have no way of knowing I closed the browser - unless, you tell it somehow. Typically you do this with a bit of javascript and listen for the browser close event and call the server to tell them they closed the browser.

On this call, you can invalidate that user's session and that should remove it from your active sessions list

Alternatively, you you add session timeout on the server which will remove the sessions upon expiry of certain amount of time.